# Confusion about what ref/heads/[branch-name] means

Tags: git, branch

Currently I want to perform a rebase on my local branch , lets call this branch `X`. I want to rebase it onto my local branch `Y`. I'm using the WebStorm IDE to do this and in the `onto` dropdown it lists a whole bunch of `ref/heads/[branch-name]`. What are these? How do they compare to simply entering `branch-name`? Which do I wan't if I want to `onto` the local branch `Y`?

Comment: not sure about the IDE but using console - git checkout <revision to check out> should work. That would be branch revision number

Comment: Just do `git rebase Y` if you want to rebase on local `Y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.git/ref/heads/BRANCHNAME` is just the file in which `git` stores the information (simply the commit hash) about that branch. I don't know your IDE, but I'd assume/hope that they just display that filename in your dropdown list for whatever reason while using the correct (simple) branch name in the actual git command.